# Avoiding redefinition of a macro-defined class

Tags: c++, class, macros

Is there a mechanism in C++ that I could use to implement a macro such that the macro defines a class and at the same time multiple invocations of the macro do not result in the class redefinition error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since a macro cannot generate any C++ Preprocessor directives, there isn't a way for the definition of a macro to generate a `#define` that protects if from being re-generated.  You'd have to handle it with separate preprocessor controls, somehow:

```
#define CLASS_GENERATOR_MACRO(x, y, z) ...defines class x with attributes y, z...

#ifndef GENERATED_CLASS_A
#define GENERATED_CLASS_A
CLASS_GENERATOR_MACRO(a, int, vector<std::string>);
#endif /* GENERATED_CLASS_A */
```

However, there is nothing that automatically enforces only one use of `CLASS_GENERATOR_MACRO` to create class `a`.  That is, the file can also contain:

```
CLASS_GENERATOR_MACRO(a, double, double);
```

and the compiler will complain about the redefinition of the class (if both appear in the same scope).

A macro can generate an invocation of `_Pragma`.  There's an outside chance that your system provides a pragma that can help.  But there most likely isn't a portable solution using pragmas.

Answer (score -1):

This solution assumes that the desired behaviour is to instantiate a new class with each use of the macro, but with different names.

It is possible to combine the use of the [`__LINE__` macro](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__LINE__.html) and the [pre-processor token pasting operator `##`](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/token-pasting-operator.html) to generate unique tokens during macro instantiation.

```
#define LOCAL_CLASS(_Base) class _Base ## __LINE__ { /* class definition */ }
```

This can then be used as such:

```
LOCAL_CLASS(SomeBase);
LOCAL_CLASS(SomeBase);
```

which will generate the following code (assuming that the macros are instantiated on lines 2 and 3 of the source file:

```
class SomeBase2 { /* class definition */ };
class SomeBase3 { /* class definition */ };
```

The downside to this solution is that the name of the generated class changes depending on where in the file it is declared and therefore can't be relied upon. This is not an issue if say, the class is not meant to be consumed by the user of the macro; the class is holding information which is automatically registered by the macro with an external library.